# How to 'freeze' my running tensorflow with cuda installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

Using the tag [tensorflow], there are plenty of problems on this page from people who try to get their installation running.

I managed to install tensorflow with a GPU backend using this installation (note, the versions are outdated by now)

https://www.pytorials.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-10-0-for-python-on-ubuntu/

After a few updates, the GPU backend stopped running for tensorflow.

If I manage to get it to work again, what can I do to stop the packages from updating until they are not compatible any more? Generally, I'd like my system to update, but not the nvidia/cuda/tensorflow part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are specific packages that you would like `apt` to *not* update, you can "hold" them:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <packagename>
```

This will allow all other updates to be performed as normal. If you decide to update the software in the future, you can "unhold" the package like this:

```
apt-mark unhold <packagename>
```

Be aware that there is a possibility that holding a package for *too long* (several years) can result in warning messages when updating software that relies on newer versions of that package.